# How to use crypt() and the password_hash() function together?

Tags: php, password-hash

I am new to PHP and now learning about password security. I read about the `crypt()` and `password_hash()` function in [PHP documentation](http://php.net). I understand the `crypt()` and `password_hash()` function alone but how do I use them together? Do I still have to define a salt in crypt() function of leave it blank like `password_hash(crypt($password,''),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to use them together?

Comment: Won't it make the password more secured? I mean if I provide a static salt in crypt() function the password will always be hashed with that salt. But as far as I understand password_hash() function will generate a random hash for the crypt() function every time so it till be more secured. Or am I just understanding to purpose of this function wrong..?

Comment: Sure you would be adding more entropy to the final hash produced by password_hash, though how your using crypt it would produce a different hash. Instead, you should provide the crypto parameters or just use hash() instead. https://3v4l.org/WRYfC

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice explanation and example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) internally uses the crypt() function. It is a wrapper which takes care of all the possible pitfalls, like the generation of a cryptographically safe salt, or the choice of the suitable algorithm.

So there is no need to combine the functions, and no need to generate a salt on your own, just use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` and you are fine.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($_POST['password'], $existingHashFromDb);
```